# Add new instance of class to element in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm going to attempt to make my question as clear as possible so here's some background. Basically I have a variety of different classes (Client, Address, Phone etc) that I want to store together in an ArrayList for Client. My constructor for Client includes a string for name as well as an instance of Address and another instance of Phone. The clients are then added into an ArrayList.

What I want to be able to do is to add a second Phone instance to an existing Client element within the ArrayList by first searching for the name of the client within the list and then using a method to add another Phone (description and number) without overwriting the existing Phone.

```
//method I'm working on to achieve adding a new Phone

public void addTelephoneNr(){
        System.out.println("Namn of customer to add new phone number to: ");
        String nameIn = scr.next();
        for (int a = 0 ; a<arrayClient.size() ; a++){   
            if(arrayClient.get(a).getNameClient().equalsIgnoreCase(nameIn)){
                Phone newPhone = new Phone();
                newPhone.setPhone();
            }
    }
```

Constructor for Client:

```
public Client(String nameClient, Address addressClient, Phone phoneClient){
        this.nameClient = nameClient;
        this.addressClient = addressClient;
        this.phoneClient = phoneClient;
    }
```

If I'm not making much sense, I'll try to answer questions that I haven't thought of myself.

Comment: Is the list defined as `List<Client>`? I ask because your question implies that you want to store several different classes of objects in your list.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify if your Client class has the proper member to store more than one phone. If it does, define an `addPhone` method, and call it in your loop :

```
        if(arrayClient.get(a).getNameClient().equalsIgnoreCase(nameIn)){
            Phone newPhone = new Phone();
            newPhone.setPhone();
            arrayClient.get(a).addPhone(newPhone);
        }
```

Comment: thank you for your input. I compared your answer with the one I received from André and managed to find a working solution. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If a client can have more than one phone number, I would use a list of phone numbers instead of a single one:

```
private List<Phone> phoneNumbers;

public Client(String nameClient, Address addressClient, Phone phoneClient){
        this.nameClient = nameClient;
        this.addressClient = addressClient;
        this.phoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        this.phoneNumbers.add(phoneClient);
}

public void addPhoneNumber(Phone phoneClient){
        this.phoneNumbers.add(phoneClient);
}
```

Then use that `addPhoneNumber()` method in your loop.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I managed to get the method to work fine with this help. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list only contains `Client` objects then it's just a matter of finding the client given a name and adding the number:

```
class Client {
    private List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;
    private String name;
    public boolean hasName(String name) {
        return this.name.equals(name);
    }
    public addNumber(PhoneNumber phoneNumber) {
        phoneNumbers.add(phoneNumber);
    }
}

List<Client> clients;

public void addNumberToClient(String name, PhoneNumber phoneNumber) {
    clients.stream()
        .filter(client -> client.hasName(name))
        .forEach(client -> client.addNumber(phoneNumber));
}
```

This will add the number to all clients with the given name (if they should be unique then that should be checked as they are added and you could use `.findFirst().ifPresent(...)` instead of `.forEach(...)`).

If the list contains other classes as well it gets a bit more complicated.